# Why inference of SavedModel slower on tf.keras than tf.saved_model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

What I did:

- convert the `.weights` to `SavedModel` (.pb), using `tf.keras.models.save()`
- load the new model file in two ways below:

```
# 1st way: tf.saved_model.load
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
infer = model.signatures['serving_default']
res = infer(tf.constant(batch_data))

# 2nd way: tf.keras.models.load
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
res = model.predict(batch_data)
```

The first runs at 15 FPS, while the second runs at 10 FPS, 1.5x slower...

My ultimate goal is to output both *intermediate layer outputs* and *final predictions*. And the only (simple) way to achieve this in TF2 is by `tf.keras.Modul(model.inputs, [<layer>.output, model.output])`. I need that loaded model to be an keras object to implement this.

So how could I use `keras` way and maintain the same inference speed?

Comment: I also try use `.h5` + `tf.keras`, resulting in same 10 FPS. Doe it simply imply that `tf.saved_model` is just faster than `tf.keras`?... Why?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43496#issuecomment-700292862) helps you?

Comment: @TFer2 thanks for the reply. I saw this one and knew that two model objects are not the same. My question is how to make my model runs in `Keras object` as fast as in `tf2 model object` (with same architecture and weigths)